# Using Rospy to check on empty topic

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to code a simple publisher and subscriber.
However, I realized that whenever Ros is subscribing to a topic, e.g.:

rospy.subscriber("/chatter",string,callback)

it will always wait for the topic in the callback function.
In this example, lets assume there is no '/chatter' topic published and the user himself had type the wrong topic. I wish to create a some kind of warning to users that warn them regarding "chatter" has not yet been publish or empty. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360700/using-rospy-to-check-on-empty-topic/) by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a bit of a misunderstanding here.

> it will always wait for the topic in the callback function

The code is not "waiting" in the callback function. The callback function is fired once a message is received, otherwise it will not be called at all.

Also note that you will get a warning on the terminal when you launch a node that is subscribing to a (published) topic which has another topic type. if by "user himself had typed the wrong topic" you mean this is really just a typo, the python interpreter will throw an exception, if the type does not exist

About your question:

> I wish to create a some kind of warning to users that warn them regarding "chatter" has not yet been publish

see #q237789

> or empty.

If by "empty" you mean that a `std_msgs/String` message is published to the `chatter` topic, you should add this check in the callback:

```
if len(msg.data) == 0:
    rospy.logwarn("Message empty")
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0